# JQuery : Set iframe height dynamically by content

Tags: jquery, iframe

I´m trying to find working jquery script for setting iframe height equal to content height.

I found this:

```
$("#IframeId").load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("html").height() );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/kkSSH/)

but is working only for old versions of jquery.

Any ideas for v3.3?

Comment: No @Sylent, its not working due to jQuery 3.x version. So its not duplicate. The OP said that its working with old versions of jquery and of course it will. But its not working with jQuery v3.x because it hasn't `.load(), .unload(), and .error()`functions.

Comment: [Here is the updated jquery code](http://jsfiddle.net/9rg3vkcc/)

Comment: You're right removed the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this and you will be good to go:

```
$("#IframeId").on("load",function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("html").height() );
});
```

Notice that, I have used `.on("load")` instead of `.load()`. Because:

```
 .load(), .unload(), and .error() have been removed with jquery 3.x
```

Therefore, you need to change:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

to

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {});
```

[Here is the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/9rg3vkcc/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because updated version of `jQuery` uses [`on` API method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach events.

```
$("#IframeId").on("load",function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("html").height() );
});
```

[Here is the working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jkx404d/)